# sequelize.fn distinct value does not give all the columns for the criteria

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My query is as shown below:

```
db.orderUser.findAll({
                where: {partner_id: req.user.id},
                attributes: [
                    [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('user_email')), 'user_email'],
                ]
            }).then((info) => {
                response.sendsuccessData(res, 'Your user contact list', info);
            })
```

In the result, I only get `user_email` column. So is there a way to get all the column for the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `concat` the values by obtaining it from the `Model.rawAttributes`

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    User.create({
      username: 'test123',
      name: 'test'
    })
      .then(() => {
        User.findAll({
          attributes: [
            [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('username')), 'username'],
          ].concat(Object.keys(User.rawAttributes)),
        }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to `exclude` columns that I get by `concat` ?

Comment: It's an array.. so all the array functions would apply. You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the values you don't want